# how to shortly check a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with 3 text inputs with function to validate them on submit like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm(this.form)">
```

and checkForm():

```js
var pattern_name = /^([a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF]+[ '-]?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF]+){1,30}$/;
var pattern_email = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

function checkForm(){
 $("form.formul :input[type=text]").each(function(){
  var input = $(this);
  var value = input.val();
  if (value=="") {
   console.log("l'input est vide");
   return false;
  }
  else{
   console.log(value);
   return false;
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.info-user{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.info-user input{
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm(this.form)">   
    <div class="civilite">
        <input type="radio" name="civ" value="Mme." id="mme" class="inline-radio"/>
        <label for="mme" class="civ-radio">Mme</label>
        <input type="radio" name="civ" value="Mlle." id="mlle" class="inline-radio"/>
        <label for="mlle" class="civ-radio">Mlle</label>
        <input type="radio" name="civ" value="M." id="m" class="inline-radio"/>
        <label for="m" class="civ-radio">M</label>
    </div>
    <div class="info-user">
        <input type="text" name="prenom" placeholder="Prénom"/>
  <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom"/>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
  <input type="image" name="image" value="submit" id="cta" />
    </div>
</form>
```

but when validating the form on submit, the console say: "l'input est vide" and reload the form...

I want to stop the validation until the form is valid

If I need to send the false statement to the function checkForm, I must transmit the false statement through the `.each` function?

like this?

```js
function checkForm(e){
    if(e == false){
        return false; 
    }
 $("form.formul :input[type=text]").each(function(){
  var input = $(this);
  var value = input.val();
  if (value=="") {
   console.log("l'input est vide");
   checkForm(false);
  }
  else{
   console.log(value);
  }
 });
}
```

it's not a little weird?

Comment: `$("form.formul")` expects the `<form>` to have the "formul" class; yours does not.

Comment: what do you want? return false stops the validation and the submitting until the submi button is pressed again.

Comment: @ Pointy : I just forget to add that class in my form tag :)
@ Jonas : I need to stop the user until the 3 fields are not filled or incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return the result of validation in checkForm.
try this:

```
function checkForm(){
    var isValid = true;
    $("form.formul :input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        var value = input.val();
        if (value=="") {
            // input is required!
            console.log("l'input est vide");
            isValid = false;
        }
        else{
            console.log(value);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```